# How to prevent Rails controller generator to modify config/routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator

Sometimes I run a command like `rails g controller foo index` to generate skeletons for controller and template.

Because I don't want to have helpers and assets for every controller, I put following codes into `config/application.rb`:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.helper false
  g.assets false
end
```

There is another thing I don't want to happen. The generator adds a line `get "foo/index"` to my `config/routes.rb`. How can I prevent it?

Comment: Is someone going to create a pull request for this feature?

Comment: @IvanDenisov it's now part of Rails as of Rails 4.2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of Rails 4.2, it's possible to disable route generation with the following code in your application.rb:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.skip_routes  true
end
```

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/4b173b8ed90cb409c1cdfb922914b41b5e212cb6

Answer (score 4):

Looks like routes generation is hardcoded. Have a look at this method
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/controller/controller_generator.rb#L12

I think, the simplest  way is to override with monkey-patch . Something like

```
module Rails
  module Generators
    class ControllerGenerator < NamedBase 
      def add_routes
        #do nothing...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

you can put it to initializer and try.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that there is no easy way to disable this feature of controller generator. It will be enough for me to confirm this fact...

Comment: This is no longer a correct answer. `skip_routes true` is the correct solution as of Rails 5

Answer (score 3):

untested...

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.resource_route false
end
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators.rb

Comment: Mr. Ronald, unfortunately, your suggestion does not change the behavior of controller generator. Tested on Rails 4.1.0.beta1. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: This should be the code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/assets/assets_generator.rb => DOES include options. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/resource_route/resource_route_generator.rb => DOES NOT include options :-(

Comment: It seems that `g.resource_route` controls the behavior of resource generator, but does not change that of controller generator.

Comment: Agree with your comment above that it doesn't look like you can stop the controller generator from generating a route (unless you don't pass it any actions - it appears if there are no actions passed no route is generated). You could also write a template to run after you generate a controller that used `gsub_file` to remove the offending routes. But I would agree if you felt that all of these solutions sound like more work than just deleting the routes from routes.rb.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid assets or helpers for all controllers, then you can write the following lines in application.rb

```
config.generators.stylesheets = false
config.generators.javascripts = false
config.generators.helper = false
```

But if want to avoid for any 1 controller then you generate controller like this

```
rails g controller test --no_assets
rails g controller test --no_helper
rails g controller test --no_javascripts
rails g controller test --no_stylesheets
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you want this particular application to not generate routes.

You can **deploy your gems to local/project folder and override them**.

In your rails project folder

```
bundle install --path /my_rails_path/lib/
```

Now you can see all of you libraries ported to your project `lib/` folder

**Go to the below file (path changes depending upon your versions)**

`lib/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/generators/rails/controller/controller_generator.rb`

and comment the function `add_routes`

```
  def add_routes
    #actions.reverse.each do |action|
    #  route %{get "#{file_name}/#{action}"}
    #end
  end
```

**NOTE:** This trick will not affect any other rails application in your system

Answer (score 2):

This is counter intuitive, but here it is what you're looking for:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.skip_routes true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your own generator! Following link will help:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html