# Rails: Some index routes are showing "/controller_name/index" others are just showing "/controller_name"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm really confused because some of my routes when I use `controllername_index_url` are routing to `/controllername/index` while other's are routing to `/controllername`.

The main difference is that when I generate the index method when I create the controller through the command line

```
rails g controller controllerName1 index
```

the route then becomes `/controller_name_1/index`.

When I create the index manually after creating the controller, it becomes `/controllername2`

In my **config/routes** I am including my controllers like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :controller_name_1
  resources :controller_name_2
end
```

And when I do a `rails routes` my routes look like

```
controller_name_1_index GET    /controller_name_1/index(.:format)                    controlle_name_1#index
controller_name_2_index GET    /controller_name_2(.:format)                             controller_name_2#index
```

Why is it automatically adding the routes differently? How can I make it so that regardless of it I generate the index methods on the command line or add them in after the fact, `controller_name_index_url` routes are always the same format? (I'm using ruby 2.4.0 and rails 5.1.2 if that's helpful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an action at the command line a route is automatically generated for it.

```
$ rails g controller ones index

     create  app/controllers/ones_controller.rb
      route  get 'ones/index' # route helper is ones_index
     ...
```

The behavior is totally agnostic of the action you're creating. It could be any action name and Rails will do the same thing

```
$ rails g controller twos smorgas

     create  app/controllers/twos_controller.rb
      route  get 'twos/smorgas' # route helper is twos_smorgas
     ...
```

When you add resources to your routes

```
resources :ones
```

you automatically get all of the default REST route helpers and routes, no matter how you create any of the REST actions.

```
$ rake routes

          ones GET    /ones(.:format)                ones#index
               POST   /ones(.:format)                ones#create
       new_one GET    /ones/new(.:format)            ones#new
      edit_one GET    /ones/:id/edit(.:format)       ones#edit
           one GET    /ones/:id(.:format)            ones#show
               PATCH  /ones/:id(.:format)            ones#update
               PUT    /ones/:id(.:format)            ones#update
               DELETE /ones/:id(.:format)            ones#destroy
```

It's best to stick with Rails convention and use the default route helpers

```
ones_url
ones_path

# not ones_index_url
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867388/how-to-prevent-rails-controller-generator-to-modify-config-routes-rb) if you want to disable the automatic route generation